# Django Admin DateTime field - combine now/today?

Tags: python, django

On Django Admin, if your model has a `DateTimeField`, this is displayed as 2 inputs, one for date and one for time, with a Today link next to the date which sets to current day, and a Now link next to time, which sets the current time.

This means if a user wants to set the date & time to the current date and time, they have to click 2 links.

Is there any way to just have one link that sets both?

Comment: Are you willing to customize the django-admin templates?

Comment: You can use `auto_now` and `auto_now_add` field option to modify date time.

Comment: Thanks, but I don't want this date to be updated automatically using auto_now/auto_now_add, it will start as blank and be entered manually by the user (it's for a Date Validated field that will be set only by a Supervisor after checking the data entered).

Answer (score 0):

Actually you can define your own form in the django admin.

**admin.py**

```
class XYModelForm(forms.ModelForm)
    class Meta:
        fields = ('field1, field2', ...)
        widgets = {
            'field1': (any widget you like)
        }

@admin.register(XYModel)
class XYModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin)
    form = XYModelForm
```

you can use your defined forms in django admin. Also you can create your widget or user any from `forms` module.